colSums function: handling Null and Empty values in R DataFrame
I'm working with the trips_2023 dataframe in R and I'm trying to get a clear overview of the number of "NA" and "" (empty) values present in each column.
I attempted the following code:
empty_count <- colSums(trips_2023 == "")
na_count <- colSums(is.na(trips_2023))

# Create a dataframe with the results
available_data_df <- data.frame(
  empty_count = empty_count,
  na_count = na_count
)

# Print the dataframe
print(available_data_df)

The output I'm getting is:
                  empty_count na_count
ride_id                     0       0
rideable_type               0       0
started_at                  0       0
ended_at                    0       0
start_station_name     875716       0
start_station_id       875848       0
end_station_name       929202       0
end_station_id         929343       0
start_lat                   0       0
start_lng                   0       0
end_lat                    NA    6990
end_lng                    NA    6990
member_casual               0       0

I'm puzzled why end_lat and end_lng are showing "NA" in the empty count column. Upon cross-checking with Power BI, I noticed they contain some "null" values. Is there a way to obtain "0" for those columns? What am I missing?
Thank you guys for your assistance.

Please try colSums(trips_2023 == "", na.rm = TRUE)

FYI, for more recognize verbiage: "null" can mean two things: NULL (length-0) is not reflected in all languages, whereas NA is what SQL and other languages call "null". The NA effectively means "it could be many things or anything", as suggested by mathematically-ambiguous calculations, though it is also very common for it to mean "no data available" aka "empty". (This comment springs from the mention of "Null" in the question title.) Glad you got your answer!

You can remove NA values in your empty strings count using na.rm argument:
colSums(trips_2023 == "", na.rm = TRUE)

